# Where to put package exceptions

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have a package "service" that consists of two modules: "service.py" and "http.py".
The "service.py" uses "http.py" module to make an HTTP request.
And I want to have this interface:

```
try:
    result = service.do(...) # does HTTP call under the hood and returns service-specific result
except ServiceError as exc:
    print(exc.as_json()) # {"message": "error", "code": "HTTP_REQUEST_TIMEOUT"}
```

So exceptions should be JSON-serializable.

The question is how to organize exceptions.

1. http.py will have its specific exceptions, the service.py will catch them and re-raise as ServiceError(, )
2. http.py will raise ServiceError defined in separate "errors.py", the "service.py" will not deal with exceptions handling

So generally, should we couple modules in the same package by shared exceptions, or is it better to keep them completely decoupled?

P.S. A separate "errors.py" module looks like a code smell, similar to "utils.py".

Comment: Does the package `service` do anything other than contain the modules `service` and `http`? Perhaps everything should be provided via `service`, with `service.service` and `service.http` being implementation details.

Comment: @chepner, I updated the question a bit. The `do` method may also call DB, for example. So the question is whether `http.py` should raise `ServiceError` or it is better to raise `HTTPError`, catch it in the `service.py` and re-raise it as `ServiceError`.

Comment: I dont think `errors` is code smell. At least not the same way `utils` can be. The problem with utils is that it is basically a "wastebasket", *anything* goes in there because we don't know where else to put it. `errors` is fine, errors go in there because they are errors.